# How do I test event.target against a React element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and want to learn by practicing. I'm trying to implement a draggable component, which wraps a child element and captures mouse events, then fires a function passed down from `props` which in turn updates the state (and the relevant CSS).

My draggable component looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class Draggable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mouseMove = this.mouseMove.bind(this);
    this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this);
    this.beginDrag = this.beginDrag.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isDragging: false,
      lastX: 0,
      lastY: 0
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    onDrag: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const child = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
    const newChild = React.cloneElement(child, {
      onMouseDown: this.beginDrag
    });

    return newChild;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMove.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUp.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseUp);
  }

  mouseMove(e) {
    if (this.state.isDragging) {
      const deltas = {
        x: e.clientX - this.state.lastX,
        y: e.clientY - this.state.lastY
      };

      this.setState({
        lastX: e.clientX,
        lastY: e.clientY
      });

      this.props.onDrag(deltas);
    }
  };

  mouseUp() {
    if (this.state.isDragging) {
      this.setState({
        isDragging: false
      });
    }
  };

  beginDrag(e) {
    this.setState({
      isDragging: true,
      lastX: e.clientX,
      lastY: e.clientY
    });
  };
}
```

With example usage:

```
import React from "react";
import Draggable from "./Draggable";

export default class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      translateX: 0,
      translateY: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      top: this.state.translateY,
      left: this.state.translateX
    };

    return (
      <Draggable onDrag={this.onDrag}>
        <div className="someComponent">
          <div className="dragContainer" style={style}>
            <div className="block">
              hello world
            </div>
            <div className="block">
              hello world
            </div>
            <div className="block">
              hello world
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Draggable>
    );
  }

  onDrag = (deltas) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      translateX: state.translateX + deltas.x,
      translateY: state.translateY + deltas.y
    }));
  };
}
```

The relevant SCSS:

```
.someComponent {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;

  .dragContainer {
    position: absolute;
  }

  .block {
    display: inline-block:
  }
}
```

---

### The problem

Dragging does work, in the sense that when I drag the container around, the contents of `.dragContainer` are translated as expected.

The thing is, dragging also works when I begin dragging from any child element (say, one of the `.block`s). I could mitigate that by testing for `e.target` in `Draggable.beginDrag`, but I have no idea what to test it against. Ideally I would compare `e.target` against the child element passed in `props` but since it's virtual DOM I'm pretty sure it won't work.

What should I compare `e.target` with? I've read about `React.createRef` but I'm not sure how to use it in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`e.target` should give access to the DOM node being clicked. Why not compare `event.target.id` to an id you give each of your blocks? Then you can do what you want based on the result of that comparison.